# How to solve the problem of the integration @SerialPort library in electron project

Tags: node.js, electron, node-serialport

I need to integrate the @serialport library in my electron project but I face this error.

> Uncaught Error: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '\?\C:\Users\PC\Desktop\electron_project_X32\node_modules@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'

I try to solve it by Making the following changes in the main.js
`app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false` but no changes

`NB: I use those version electron: ^16.1.0 && node: 16.13.2 (32-bit ) && serialport: ^10.4.0,`